# What is the big hole next to the 2mm hole that caused the 2018-08-30 Soyuz MS-09 / ISS leak?

Tags: iss, soyuz-spacecraft, leak

The small hole in this picture is being reported as the cause of the ISS leak. What is the large hole next to it on the perpendicular surface? The one that appears to have been drilled by an amatuer with a hole saw? Does it have a purpose?

[image]

Comment: There is a similar hole at the lowerright side of the image. These are no holes from inside to outside. There is no need for clean cut holes if they are there only to save weight.

Comment: @Uwe You think these holes were cut to save weight? That seems very unlikely. Also, there are lots of reasons to deburr holes e.g. keeps debris from breaking off later, rounds off sharp edges that could snag or cut something.

Comment: Weight-saving holes are common in aerospace vehicle structures. Like the ones in the  ribs of this airplane wing. https://www.cfinotebook.net/graphics/aerodynamics-and-performance/aircraft-components-and-structure/wing-construction.png

Comment: That said, I agree with you about the apparent low quality of this work.

Comment: In still confused by the geometry of these holes- I can’t really see how the smaller hole breaches the pressure vessel, but the larger doesn’t!

Comment: Looks like the big holes are painted, but the small hole is not.  That may be a clue to when they were made.

Comment: Also, are there other pictures of the inside of similar modules, to which we can compare?

Comment: @Jack the big hole and the small hole are perpendicular to each other - since the small one apparently goes through the hull, perhaps the big one is lined up with the axis of the vehicle.

Comment: @OrganicMarble oh my word, I've been looking at it wrong this whole time! I've been seeing the larger hole as more distant than the smaller, damn you [schroeder stairs!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schroeder_stairs)

Comment: @foobarbecue: "That seems very unlikely" It seems you are very wrong.

Comment: @Uwe, it seems I am indeed wrong and you are very right!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a lightening hole.

The structure you see on the upper right of the image is a ring frame with a flanged C-channel cross-section that goes around the circumference of the Soyuz orbital module pressure shell.  Below is a crude text diagram of what you're looking at:

```
            __________
           |          |
           |          | <-- lightening holes here
           |          |    leak here
           |          |   /
    _______|          |__v____  
------------------------- --------
   ^
   Pressure wall here
```

The leak hole is in the flange of the C-channel, and the lightening hole (one of many, regularly spaced along the channel) is in the "vertical" wall of the C-channel.  The "ragged" appearance of the lightening hole is actually residue from some tape that was covering the ring frame.  You can see some of that tape at the bottom center of the image.

Comment: Very good graphic to explain where is the pressure wall and where the ring frame. Also where are the lightening holes and the leak. If the leak would be covered by the ring frame, fixing it would be difficult to impossible.